# Serialize a generic collection using gson

Tags: java, gson

I would like to serialize the following class using gson:

```
public class SerializableCollection<T> {

    private final Collection<T> collection;
```

The problem is that the item's type is lost after deserialization. For example, if the collection contains enum entries, the deserialized instance will contain Strings. I know that the generic type is erased at compile time, but is there a way to tell gson to serialize the type of the collection elements so that at deserialization it will be able to instantiate the proper objects?

I tried with TypeToken:

```
final Type typeToken = new TypeToken<SerializableCollection<T>>() {}.getType();
```

but it doesn't seem to work.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Gson user guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Generic-Types) you need to use TypeToken, but with the correct type instead of T.

So if you change your Type object to:

```
final Type typeToken = new TypeToken<SerializableCollection<TheCorrectClassName>>() {}.getType();
```

It should work.

But therefore you still need to know the correct type at compile time. Without knowing the type it's not possible, I think.